# Json: получение текста

Tags: json, php

Есть вот такой текст  в `json`:

```
"tasks":[{"id":3,"target":320,"progress":0,"description":1},{"id":2,"target":3,"progress":0,"description":1},{"id":15,"target":4,"progress":0,"description":5},{"id":16,"target":3,"progress":0,"description":1},{"id":17,"target":5,"progress":0,"description":4},{"id":18,"target":2,"progress":0,"description":1},{"id":19,"target":1,"progress":0,"description":0},{"id":21,"target":3,"progress":0,"description":1}]
```

Как получить вот такое:

```
$zID1 = '3';
$zID2 = '2';
$zID3 = '15';
$zID4 = '16';
$zID5 = '17';
$zID6 = '18';
$zID7 = '19';
$zID8 = '21';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как-то так:

```
$zID = array();  
$a = json_decode($json, TRUE);  
for($i=0; $i < count($a['task']); $i++)  
    $zID[] = $a['tasks'][$i]['id'];  
var_dump($zID);
```

Comment: extract($zID);

Кавычка после id

Comment: кавычку исправил, спасибо

Comment: Не работает почему-то элементы после этого кода не работают.

Comment: $zID - это массив, к его элементам нужно обращаться как $zID[0], $zID[1], ...

Comment: Я это понял, но после вот этих строк, код который идёт после не работает

Comment: пардон, но я же не вижу вашего кода, который идет после моего.. :)

Comment: Что-то у меня Ваш пример тоже не работает.
Изменить необходимо строку с переменной $a.
Сделать такой: $a = json_decode($json, true);
Либо изменить весь код, на такой:
$zID = array();  
$a = json_decode($json);  
for($i=0; $i < count($a->tasks); $i++)  
$zID[] = $a->tasks[$i]->id;  
var_dump($zID);

Comment: будет достаточно поставить в json_decode вторым параметром TRUE

Comment: array(0) { }

Comment: Вы попробовали то, что я сказал? сам проверял и не может быть массив пустым.

Comment: И первый код пробовал и ваш тоже